# Best (safest) way to store database credentials for AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, database, credentials

In the past I have stored database credentials (username, password) in another file (outside of the web directory) and included this in a PHP page to make connections with the database.  Since I have started doing a lot of database interaction via AJAX, I have to change how I do this, since the AJAX script cannot `include` a script outside the web directory.

In order to deal with AJAX database connections, I need a good secure way to get the username and password data to the AJAX script.  What is the best (secure and handy) way to do this?  If i simply put my database credentials file in the web directory, what permissions to give it?  Is this a good/bad idea?

Thanks a lot!

** EDIT **

Apparently there is not problem including files outside of web root directory, I was mistaken.  Thanks very much, this probably changes things for me... :-/

** EDIT 2 **

Indeed that changed everything for me, I was able to include the database config file which i was using in all the pages (which resided outside the web root), so this is great!

Comment: Why can't your AJAX script include files outside of the web directory?

Comment: Why can't "the AJAX script" access files outside the webroot? Are you trying to send the database credentials to *the client*?!

Comment: I'm assuming that is because he's balancing private / public access via folder structure... which would make it easier for him to defend against traversal attacks and other type of backend file access abuse

Comment: You are mixing up Javascript and PHP. Ajax is a technology used by javascript to do HTTP requests. PHP handles your database connection and answers those requests, but it doesn't matter to PHP whether you send the request via Ajax or a normal HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes i realize my mistake.  I did not mix up js and php, just something i thought was true for a while and never tested it, of course I just tested it and it works fine, like that...  sorry about that.

Comment: @basti unless of course he's using something like couchDB's restful js interface... which then removes the need for a php layer as a db abstraction layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not opposed to changing things up a little bit, I think you should use your backend to interface with the database, and just use your ajax to hit those interfaces to the DB. that way you dont have to ever "Store db creds" client side

OR if you absolutely must save client side, you should figure out a way to reduce your access to a hashed / salted key that you save in a session cookie or something

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AJAX, you should just call a php-page for instance insert.php. Within this php you can include any php you want(even outside the root-folder). so you could just include db-credentials.php in the insert.php